# Need help to transform table. Used pivot but unable to get desired output

Tags: sql, r

[Sample data][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCa7f.jpg

[expected output][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gAE9.jpg

Comment: Do not use images. Include the data

Comment: This [page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) has some good pointers on how best to ask a question to have the best chance of getting a prompt helpful answer